# Access String variable from one if statement in another

Tags: java, if-statement, scope

I am new to java coming from C#.

If I have a string that gets set in an "if-statement" is there a way to carry that string's value to other if statements?

E.g. I set the `String hi` to carry the text "hello" in an if statement, but now have a completely separate if statement, and would like to use the value set to the `String hi` in the previous if statement.

My issue is that the veriable can't be set until certain things in the if statement happen.

```
if(add.equals(temp)) {
    System.out.println ("What is the first number?");
    numberone = listen.nextDouble ();
    System.out.println ("What is the second number?");
    numbertwo = listen.nextDouble ();
    numberthree = numberone + numbertwo;
    previousproblem = numberthree;
    System.out.println ("The answer is " + numberthree);
}
```

So later on, in another `if` statement I, need to reference `previousproblem`, but it can't be set until this `if` statement, as `numberthree` isn't set until this statement.

Comment: Can you elaborate more clearly?

Comment: What would you do in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is identical to C# in this respect, all you need to do is declaring the variable *outside* both if statements, and set its initial value:

```
String s = null;
if (someCondition) {
    s = "hello";
}
if (anotherCondition) {
    System.out.println("s is "+s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm just beginning to learn it as of yesterday and couldn't find anything regarding the matter.

Comment: @user185812 You are welcome! If you have experience with C#, Java should not feel too much "foreign" to you. The latest additions, such as LINQ, are missing, and the generics are implemented rather differently, but the control flow should feel very much at home.

Answer (score 0):

Define the string, before you start you if and else sequence.

```
String str1,str2;
if(true) {
   // ... true part
   str1 = "hello";
} else { 
   // ... false part
}
```

Now in another `If`

```
if(true) {
    str2 = str1; //assign the value of str1 to str2 demonstrating the use str1 in another if
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**A variable is available in the scope it is declared; a scope can be easily identified by enclosing `{ }`.**

So if you need a variable to be accessed across two `if` statements you need to declare them in the scope of both `if` statements.

```
if(condition) {

}
if(another condition) {

}
```

to use a variable inside both if you should declare it outside the first if statement like this:

```
String myVariable = "";

if(condition) {
    //myVariable operation
}
if(another condition) {
    //myVariable another operation    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See Simple Concept . After method Define Variable =null Like :

```
Condition =null;

if (Condition == true){
System.out.println(Condition);
else{
System.out.println(Condition);
}
```

So now Condition Value Should Be Access Out side of the block